# get Specific Id from json file

Tags: c#, json

this is my json file

```
{
    {
        "@odata.context": "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives('me')/items('root')/children/$entity",
        "createdBy": {
            "application": {
                "displayName": "Nopbackup",
                "id": "4c190e01"
            },
            "user": {
                "displayName": "pallav jha",
                "id": "611c19eb038d5aa1"
            }
        },
        "createdDateTime": "2016-05-12T07:25:36.463Z",
        "cTag": "adDo2MTFDMTlFQjAzOEQ1QUExITEyNC42MzU5ODYzODk5MTI3MDAwMDA",
        "eTag": "aNjExQzE5RUIwMzhENUFBMSExMjQuMw",
        "id": "611C19EB038D5AA1!124",
        "lastModifiedBy": {
            "application": {
                "displayName": "Nopbackup",
                "id": "4c190e01"
            },
            "user": {
                "displayName": "pallav jha",
                "id": "611c19eb038d5aa1"
            }
        },
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-05-12T08:36:31.27Z",
        "name": "Nopbackup",
        "parentReference": {
            "driveId": "611c19eb038d5aa1",
            "id": "611C19EB038D5AA1!105",
            "path": "/drive/root:"
        },
        "size": 0,
        "webUrl": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=611C19EB038D5AA1!124",
        "fileSystemInfo": {
            "createdDateTime": "2016-05-12T07:25:36.463Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2016-05-12T08:36:31.27Z"
        },
        "folder": {
            "childCount": 0
        }
    }
}
```

i want to get this  "id": "4c190e01" from json

```
dynamic value = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
string id = Convert.ToString(value.id[0]);
```

this is my code but i am not getting 4c190e01 id

Comment: i want to get   "id": "4c190e01" value  but i am getting this value  "id": "611c19eb038d5aa1"  by this code   dynamic value = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);  JObject hh = JObject.Parse(result);
                string name = (string)hh["id"];

Comment: The id "4c190e01" is in your json 2x. Which one you like to refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, Your json is invalid.
You've to remove one `{` from top and `}` from the bottom and then use the following code:

```
 dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
 string id = jsonObj.createdBy.application.id.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your code as following...

```
dynamic valuePoco = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
string id = Convert.ToString(valuePoco.createdBy.application.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the path to the desired property. If you want to select the element with `4c190e01` as id, you can use

```
string id = value.createdBy.application.id;
```

or

```
string id = value.lastModifiedBy.application.id;
```

depending on your needs.

As it was pointed out, you'd need to fix your JSON first and remove the first `{` and the last `}`